# MySQL query - how can we select a multi column in specific value over 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, inner-join

I have the following tables in my database:

1. clients (table name = 'reps')
2. projects (table name = 'verkocht')
3. milestones (table name = 'milestones')

Client X has 300 projects. 200 of them does not have milestones. 100 of them has milestones. I get right now all 300 projects. my goal is getting 100 projects. If a project does not have a milestone, then why would I show that project?

My goal is getting **only** all projects which have milestones.

I tried this but did not work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `clients` 
FROM reps c
INNER JOIN verkocht p ON p.client = c.clients
INNER JOIN milestones m ON m.verkocht_id = p.id
GROUP BY p.id
```

I also tried this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `reps` 
WHERE `clients` IN (SELECT * 
                    FROM `milestones` 
                    WHERE `client` = 'X')
```

My query of projects is this:

```
$clientValue = $_COOKIE['client'];
$queryProject = " SELECT `id`, `beschrijving`, `client` FROM `verkocht` WHERE `beschrijving` != '' AND `client` = '{$clientValue}' ";
```

Example: If I select client 'stackoverflow' I can choose 200 projects. If i click on project 129 I see nothing because project 129 has no milestones. It makes no sense when I select a project with has no milestone. that is why I want to select project which **has** milestones

**EDIT**: added database tables

Table 'reps'

```
        1   ID             int(5)       AUTO_INCREMENT  
        2   clients        tinytext
```

Table 'verkocht'

```
        1   ID             int(11)      AUTO_INCREMENT  
        2   client         varchar(130)  
        4   beschrijving   tinytext
```

Table 'milestones'

```
        1   ID             int(11)      AUTO_INCREMENT  
        2   titel          varchar(64) 
        4   omschrijving   text
        5   client         varchar(40)
        6   verkocht_id    int(11)
```

Comment: Change to `LEFT JOIN` then.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: Why GROUP BY when no aggregate functions are used. And why combine with SELECT DISTINCT?

Comment: Why? I want only data which is not double

Comment: What do you want to show actually? Projects that have milestones? Or clients that have projects that have milestones? Or what else?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text (not images.)

Comment: MySql, i editted my title

Comment: @jarlh because my column has double data

Comment: @ThorstenKettner "Or clients that have projects that have milestones? "

Comment: Duplicate rows?

Comment: And `clients` is a column in `reps`? Is this the primary key? (It would be way better to have matching names, e.g. clients.client_id or reps.rep_id.

Comment: Since I don't know your data model, I can't say if your query is theoretically correct. Now since I trust MySQL quite a bit, I think you have multi column keys in your table of which you only compare parts.

Comment: @Ronald i added it in my question

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Why does the milestone table have a `client` column? If a project belongs to 'Miller', can a milestone of that project belong to 'Smith'? And do you want 'Miller' in your results or 'Smith' or both?

Comment: Anyway, your datamodel seems flawed and you should fix it. This starts with names consistency (do you want to call it reps or clients?) But most of all you should not relate records by the clients' names, when you have IDs. (I.e. `verkocht` should have a column `reps_id`, not `client`).

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Haha lol i know that table names and colmuns are bad i did not do that. I am at my internship i am ''learning'' to develop websites. But i know that this a mess is. i can not change is. they use this. if i change something to work it form my project, then de other things will stuck. i dont want to do that. thanks... btw i can not ask my internship-leader to ask to fix he will say:: it is your bussiness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to show clients for whom exist projetcs for which exists milestones:

```
select *
from reps
where clients in 
(
  select client 
  from verkocht
  where id in (select verkocht_id from milestones)
);
```

Comment: I tried this, i still get projects that has no milestones.

Comment: sir, do  I also need to change my projects query? my projectsquery is in my qeustion

Comment: With my query you cannot get projects without milestones. You are mistaken.

Comment: I am Seriously sir. This is a real example and i am not joking :  I have Client X and Project 280. I do not have milestones with verkocht_id 280.

Comment: **EXAMPLE:**
If i do this (which is correct)
SELECT id, beschrijving, client FROM verkocht WHERE id = 280 
i get this: ID: 280 | bechrijving: example | client: example

If i do this(which is correct)
SELECT id, omschrijving from milestones where verkocht_id = 280
i get this: empty result

Comment: And you say that `select * from verkocht where id in (select verkocht_id from milestones)` does return the project 280? I doubt that.

Comment: no sir re-read it.. i said: If i do this (which is correct)
SELECT id, beschrijving, client FROM verkocht WHERE id = 280 
i get this: ID: 280 | bechrijving: example | client: example

Comment: And If i do this(which is correct)
SELECT id, omschrijving from milestones where verkocht_id = 280
i get this: empty result

Comment: Yes. You say the following: **1)** Project 280 exists (your *from verkocht* query). **2)** No milestone for project 280 exists (your *from milestones* query). **3)** My query returns projects without milestones. **Now:** My subquery that returns projects is `select * from verkocht where id in (select verkocht_id from milestones)`. So does this or does this not return project 280?

Comment: i tried this: select * from verkocht where id in (select verkocht_id from milestones) and I get total 120 milestones which has all of them projects. thanks sir!

Answer (score 0):

Since all correct looking queries fail, I think you have duplicates (with regard to the ID) in verkocht.

```
select *
  from reps
 where clients in (
       select client
         from verkocht v
        where id in (
              select verkocht_id
                from milestones m
               where m.client = v.client
         )
  );
```

If my suspicion is correct the above query should work.

Now apart from this query, you might want to overthink your data model.
You have a column 'clients' in the reps table with datatype 'tinytext'. This obviously serves as a candidate key, since it is used to reference a reps by verkocht. This column in verkocht has a different data type though. And the data type of 'client' in milestones is again another one.

It would be better to add a column 'reps_id' to both verkocht and milestones. (if the client column is indeed a reference to the clients (note the plural) column in reps)

Comment: Unless the tables are MyISAM (unlikely), then this conjecture cannot hold.

Comment: Sir, Those tables are not editable. I am at the internship and I use this those table which are made by them. I can not change or add something

Comment: OK, that's bad luck. The model isn't the best I've ever seen. Different spelling and different data types for columns that apparently have the same meaning.

Comment: @Strawberry Since both the inner joins and the subquery joins turn up with "non-matches", it must be either a partial key compare or an extremely severe bug in MySQL. Since I can't imagine the latter and I am impressed by the data model at the same time, my guess is the former reason.
I don't know why a storage structure ISAM would have an influence in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Only projects (verkocht) which have milestones, one way (just giving the internal project id)

```
select distinct verkocht_id from 'milestones';
```

IF milestones.verkocht_id = verkocht.id then:

**Projects with milestones**

```
select distinct v.*
from verkocht v
inner join milestones m verkocht.id = m.verkocht_id;
```

**Projects without milestones**

```
select distinct v.*
from verkocht v
left join milestones m verkocht.id = m.verkocht_id
where m.id IS NULL;
```

Beyond that you have a mismatch of data tyoes/lengths  of "client"

```
  2   clients        tinytext
  2   client         varchar(130)  
  5   client         varchar(40)
```

and I'm not goind to sort out that for you without a lot more visibility of your data.